# Training loss fluctuates and does not go down effectively

Tags: tensorflow

I am training the SSD efficientnet B0 on Pascal Voc 2012 dataset from scratch (It needs to be from scratch) with tensorflow object detection API, i have been training for about more than 60k step with batch size of 5 (More than that and i have OOM error), however the loss fluctuates alot and really struggle to drop even abit as can seen in [training loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OBS1.png), has my training gone wrong or is it the optimizer that i set is not suitable? How would i solve it?

The optimizer configurations is as below:

```
optimizer {
    adam_optimizer: { 
        learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
            initial_learning_rate: .01
            schedule {
                step: 20000
                learning_rate: .001
            }
            schedule {
                step: 40000
                learning_rate: .0001
            }
            schedule {
                step: 60000
                learning_rate: .00001
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: have you standardized/normalized your inputs? have you tried to reduce the momentum of Adam?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia  i didnt do any standardize or normalize on the dataset, and i dont think there is an argument of momentum for Adam, although i do used the momentum optimizer to try and it had similar result.

Comment: You should normalize/standardize your dataset, in order to reduce the variance... `beta_2` is the decay of the momentum, the closer to 0, the less momentum will be used at time passes